# Java API to connect to SVN server via https protocol

Tags: java, api, svn, repository

I want to implement a java program that connects to SVN repository server (eg. `https://myrepository`) and gets all the files and the folders inside it.
Do you know any java api can help me to reach this goal?

And how can I implement the authentication?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've use svnkit in the past: http://svnkit.com/

Comment: Perhaps, it doesn't works with HTTPS protocol! Can you also post some sample code? I am interested especially in the authentication code!

Comment: http://svnkit.com/documentation.html Shows on that page that HTTPS is supported.  I think you're okay.

Comment: This gives a pretty good example of geting the tree of an svn repo: http://wiki.svnkit.com/Printing_Out_A_Subversion_Repository_Tree. If you're having problems authenticating over SSL, refer to the following: http://wiki.svnkit.com/Authentication#SSL_Manager